# How do I popup an alert box for verification when the user clicks a link on the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, confirm

I am building a small CMS and I have a delete option for post, pages etc. It is a link but now I need to make it show a popup alert or something when clicking on it just to verify if people really do want to delete the article.
If the user clicks "yes" then it with continue to that link and delete, but if people click "NO" then it won't let the browser to go to that link and delete the article.

I know I can do this with jQuery somehow but I am 2 days without sleeping and I can't think straight. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use jQuery to send up a [confirm dialog](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.confirm). If the user clicks OK and confirms then you can return true which will allow the link to be followed automatically. If the user clicks cancel you will [cancel the event's default](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.preventDefault) (the default for a click event on a link is to go to it) and then the link will not be followed.

**HTML:**

```
<a class="confirm" href="http://www.microsoft.com">Link</a>
```

**JavaScript (with jQuery):**

```
$(".confirm").on("click", function(event){
    if(confirm("Are you SURE....?")){
       return true;
    } else {
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
});
```

[**Try it out on jsFiddle!**](http://jsfiddle.net/adamzr/jFuJ5/)

Comment: Thank you adam this did the trick I am going to accept your answer when stckoverflow allows me

Comment: Any way to edit the buttons in the alert box, because it is in English, can I edit it to German language?

Comment: That is browser driven. If your browser is set to use German it will say the appropriate messaging.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('a.confirm').click(function() {
    return confirm('Really delete this?');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<a href='url_to_delete_page' onclick='return check()'>Click</a>
```

JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function check(){
        return confirm("Really delete it?");
}
</script>
```

Comment: I'll be really glad to know the reason behind the -1. Could you please tell me?

Comment: I would too.  It's a more optimized version of Adam's answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you make a confirm dialog, you can copy the `href` from the pressed link.

The way this code works, is it automatically binds to links with the class `confirm`.  It then modifies a confirm dialog to have the `yes` button do the original link's action, and `no` to hide the dialog.

### [demo](http://codepen.io/brigand/pen/DFqup)

The HTML:

```
<div class="dialog" id="confirmation">
  <div class="title">Are you sure?</div>
  <a href="#" class="yes">Yes</a>
  <a href="#" class="no">No</a>
</div>

<a href="#delete" class="delete confirm">Delete</a>
```

And the JavaScript.

```
$('#confirmation.dialog .no')
  .click(function(){
    $('#confirmation.dialog').hide();
});

$('a.confirm').on('click', function(){
  var $el = $(this), link = $el.attr('href'),
      $confirm = $('#confirmation.dialog'),
      $yes, $no;

  $confirm.show();
  $yes = $confirm.find('.yes');

  $yes.attr('href', link);

  return false;
});
```